# How to delete a face

Tags: faces

I was experimenting with face definitions and created a number of "test" faces that were meant to be temporary. At the end of the experiments, I wanted to clean up after myself, so I attempted `(unintern FACE)`, but the faces remained on the return value of function `(face-list)`. My guess was that the faces are stored in a different `obarray`. Then I looked at the function definition for `(face-list)` in file `faces.el`, and it gets its data from variable `face-new-frame-defaults` which is defined in `C source code`, which is a simple list, and not seemingly updated.

As a complication to testing and debugging, the doc-string for `unintern` indicates that FACE can be specified either as a string or as a symbol. However, the function behaves differently for the alternatives. This is kind of a tangent, and may be a bug in `unintern`, but it confused debugging my situation. For a normal symbol `(setq my-temp-test-symbol "HELP!")`, performing `unintern` with a string argument correctly returned `t` on symbol-found-and-uninterned and `nil` on symbol-not-found; However, when passed a symbol `'my-temp-test-symbol`, it returned `t` repeatedly.

For faces, performing `unintern` with a symbol argument always returns `t`, and with a string argument does first return `t`, and then `nil`, but the face continues to appear in the output of `(face-list)`.

Comment: `(unintern 'mysym)` always returns t since the reader sees `'mysym` interns it and only afterwards `unintern` is called with the (newly interned) symbol as argument. Opposed to that `(progn (setq symholder 'mysym) (list (unintern symholder) (unintern symholder)))`  returns `(t nil)` since the reader does not read `mysym` anymore after the `setq` but only `symholder`. The second example shows that you can pass a symbol without interning it as value of another symbol. See [Creating and Interning Symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html).

Comment: Goodness, you don't want to unintern a symbol if the face properties are the only things you are interested in.  A symbol might have a variable value and a function value and who knows what other properties besides being a face.  I mean, for `my-temp-test-symbol` then sure, go ahead -- that one is obviously yours to start with -- but in general?  Definitely not the way to go.

Comment: I strongly recommend to stay very far away from `unintern` unless you *really* know what it does.  It's a great footgun, tho.

Answer (score 2):

Faces are not held in an obarray. `unintern` won't help you to delete a face.

There's no way to completely delete a face. The best you can do is to “hide” it by removing it from the list of faces that `facep` tests and `face-list` enumerates. As you've already found, what defines a face in this respect is being present in `face-new-frame-defaults`.

There is no primitive function to remove a frame from `face-new-frame-defaults`, but you can make one. Note that I haven't fully checked for side effects, I just had a quick look at the code in `xfaces.c` and didn't see anything obviously wrong with doing this.

```el
(defun delete-face (face)
  "Delete a face. FACE can be a string or symbol.
After calling this function, `(facep FACE)' will return nil.
Note that the face should not be in use anywhere."
  (interactive (list (completing-read
              "Delete face: " face-new-frame-defaults
              nil t nil 'face-name-history)))
  (if (stringp face)
      (setq face (intern face)))
  (setq face-new-frame-defaults (assq-delete-all face face-new-frame-defaults))
  (mapc (lambda (frame)
      (let ((alist (frame-face-alist frame)))
        (assq-delete-all face alist)
        ;; There's no way to set a frame's face alist, so there's no way to
        ;; remove the first element in all circumstances.
        (when (eq (caar alist) face)
          (if (null (cdr alist))
          (setcar alist (cons nil nil))
        (setcar alist (cadr alist))
        (setcdr alist (cddr alist))))))
    (frame-list))
  (cl-remf (symbol-plist face) 'face))
```

Note that I haven't really tested this, so I don't know if bad things may happen if the face is still in use.

This doesn't remove all resources associated with the face. For example, faces have a unique identifier which is recorded in an internal array (the face numerical identifier which is stored in the symbol's `face` property), and there's no way to remove an entry from this internal array.

---

Regarding `unintern`, if you run `(unintern 'my-temp-test-symbol)`, it always returns `t`. This is correct behavior: `my-temp-test-symbol` exists when you pass it to `unintern`. If you already have an interned symbol, then by definition it exists. If you want to see `unintern` return nil, you have to pass it something that isn't an interned symbol. It can be a symbol in a different obarray, an uninterned symbol, or a string.

```el
    (let ((sym (make-symbol)))
      (unintern sym))
    (let* ((sym (intern (symbol-name (gensym))))
           (first (unintern sym))
           (second (unintern sym)))
      (list first second))
    (let* ((vec (make-vector 7 0))
           (sym (intern "foo" vec))
           (first (unintern sym vec))
           (second (unintern sym)))
      (list first second))
```

Comment: Hm, `(get 'myface 'face)` returns an id. That property does not change when one deletes the face from `face-new-frame-defaults`, does it? What does this id indicate?  The position of the face in the frame face list? `face-new-frame-defaults` is only for new frames, isn't it? I experimented a bit in the scratch buffer.

Comment: @Tobias The id is an index in an internal face array. There's no Lisp function that allows removing entries from this array. And indeed `face-new-frame-defaults` applies to new frames, but it's a bit more than that: it's also the “user interface” to faces. So removing a face from there does effectively remove the face from the user interface, even if it doesn't completely remove all traces of the face.

Comment: I am getting following error: Symbol’s value as variable is void: face-new-frame-defaults

Comment: @alper In Emacs 28 (https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/e3b8ddd5005903465ec86823559a2e884c7b13f2) it changed to `face--new-frame-defaults` with a different format.

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot really delete the faces from the internal face table of the current frame. Maybe I am mistaken in that point because I did not carefully inspect the c-source code. So I would very much appreciate acknowledgement of somebody who knows the Emacs internals better.

[Gilles](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/25/gilles) is right [in his answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48445/2370) that you can change the default faces for **newly** created frames.

I did a little experiment in the scratch buffer. The results are given as comments.

```el
(defface myface '((t :inverse-video t))
  "Doc" :group 'test)
;; => myface

(insert (propertize "test" 'font-lock-face 'myface))
;; => inverted "test" inserted into the buffer

(get 'myface 'face)
;; => 773

(setq face-new-frame-defaults (cl-delete-if (lambda (face) (string-equal (car face) "myface")) face-new-frame-defaults))
;; => new list of faces

(get 'myface 'face)
;; => 773

(unintern 'myface)
;; t

(defface myface '((t :inverse-video t))
  "Doc" :group 'test)
;; => myface

(insert (propertize "test" 'font-lock-face 'myface))
;; => inverted "test" inserted into the buffer

(get 'myface 'face)
;; => 774
```

As one sees. After the first `(get 'myface 'face)` one gets 773 and after the second -- inspit of the attempts to delete the face -- one gets 774.

Another experiment:
The following sequence of instruction gives you a new frame with only shades of gray. The old frame remains colorful. Also new input in the old frame lets font-lock colorize the text as before in the old frame.
On the other hand the new frame spies error messages about missing fonts into the message buffer.

```el
(setq old-faces face-new-frame-defaults)
(setq face-new-frame-defaults nil)
(new-frame)
```

Note, also the list returned by `(frame-face-alist)` is a list newly created from the internal face table. So destructively deleting an entry from that list does also **not** delete the entry from the internal face table.