# How can I disable font-latex-math-face?

Tags: auctex, customize-face

In [AUCTex](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX) there is `font-latex-math-face` which makes color of string in between `$` and `$` as green.

Example output:

[image]

or:

[image]

Is is possible to disable/delete `font-latex-math-face`, where the `green` color won't apply?

Could be related to: [How to delete a face](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/48443/18414)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to enable font lock inside a math environment, but you can prevent AUCTeX from recognizing the dollar as a math delimiter replacing the definition of `font-latex-match-dollar-math` with

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'font-latex
  (defun font-latex-match-dollar-math (limit)
    nil))
```

Comment: It made string color in between `$$` all white which is now more difficult to read. is it possible to keep the normal coloring

Comment: @alper see updated answer

Comment: Prefered color is default face I believe , where it also changes coloring text based on the key words like \mathrm should be blue and so on. I have put the color change in my question. Is it possible to keep the original face colors?

Comment: @alper I think now I understand what you asked

Comment: I still see the font color in between dolar sign as green :-(

Comment: Did you reload the tex buffer or executed `font-lock-fontify-buffer` in it after changing the definition? What is the output of `C-h f font-latex-match-dollar-math`?

Comment: Yes, I have run `font-lock-fontify-buffer` but no change occurs :-( It looks like unchanged: `font-latex-match-dollar-math is a native compiled Lisp function in
‘font-latex.el’.

(font-latex-match-dollar-math LIMIT)

Match inline math $...$ or display math $$...$$ before LIMIT.
`.  I added the code piece in your answer at the bottom of my `.emacs` file

Comment: The function must be re-defined after loading the original definition, see updated answer

Comment: It worked this time. Thanks for your patience to help out. Small question could only the dolar sign be green color?

Comment: I don't know, the approach of my answer is an hack, and quite ugly, it prevents AUCTeX from recognizing the dollar as a math delimiter,. I noticed that if you use `\(` and `\)` as delimiters instead of dollars the syntax highlighting is partially preserved

Comment: But I need dolar signs for the math format in the latex file, will `\( \)` cause the same affect as math format?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode